# Why does SSL_read go into infinite loop?

Tags: python, c

I am using python `socketserver` to write a server with the following handler

```
class ConnectionHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        tmp = self.request.recv(4096).strip().decode("utf8")
        self.request.send("this is the server\n".encode("utf8"))
```

on the client side I am using c code

```
int main(){
    .
    . 
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    connection(socfd, "127.0.0.1", 10001); uses the socket descriptor to connect to the server 
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, socfd);
    SSL_connect(ssl);

    // send msg to server
    char text[] = "Hello world";
    SSL_write(ssl, text, sizeof(text));
    
    // read server msg
    char buffer[10];
    SSL_read(ssl, buffer, 10);
    printf("Server replied: [%s]\n", buffer);
}
```

when running the code I get `Hello world` on the server side but the client seems to go in an infinite loop and does not output the server message

Comment: You seem to be trying to use the same port on the same computer for server and client.  Most likely your server is receiving both (actually many) messages. For a connection between two programs on the same computer use a Unix domain socket rather than a network socket.

Comment: @stark this is not the main issue and i can use another machine on the same network to do the exact same thing and the error won't be fixed